# opening a file in aix

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh, aix, cat

(AIX/ksh)
i have a chinese file ...i cant able to open it in aix using cat fully...if i give cat then some contents are missing...and if i give cat -v it is giving wierd code....even i tried with while loop to read contents,but not working...with more command i can but i cant use more in shell scripting...so please shed some idea here...many thanks

Comment: It would help if you said what you're trying to do with the file and showed a sample of the contents and what it looks like when `cat` drops part of it. Also show what your `while` loop looks like and what "not working" means (error message, deviation from expected result, etc.). What does the `locale` command tell you?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be your terminal emulator, not the cat command itself which just output the file's content without processing. Make sure your character encoding is correct, should be LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL or perhaps LANG and that your terminal can display chinese characters.

Comment: He may also want to have a look at iconv.

Comment: everything is ok with terminal emulator and lang settings...what i need is alternative to cat or more command which could read the chinese file correctly

Comment: cat is reading the file correctly; it can't do otherwise. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Maybe is your text file corrupted. Are you sure it is correct  in the first place ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with cat/more; if you don't believe it, try cp,dd,less,mcview,vi,whatever: they all read the files the same way: byte after byte, sequentially

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy I guess your comment is directed to the open poster. Beware that (s)he didn't visited stackoverflow in the last four years...